# Passing calling activity to pager adapter

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

Trying to send calling activity to pager adapter in order for these two lines to work in the pager adapter:

```
((AppCompatActivity) callingActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

((AppCompatActivity)callingActivity).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

(note using pager adapter not fragment pager adapter).

Comment: pass is via constructor? anything else?

Comment: yes constructer, android studio will not let calling activity be part of the calling to the constructer

Comment: huh? what exactly you are trying to do, it's unclear , be specific about the issue along with code

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh, did you see the edit above your comment? I'm trying to enable the "back button" and custom title in the toolbar.

Comment: @Emuna613 could you post the code for your fragment's constructor?

Comment: My bad, sorry, I was trying to pass MyActivity.class instead of MyActivity.this. lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using this code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And put this code in your activity

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), SCTypeface.TTF_REGULAR);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }

        TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_text);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbarTitle.setText("YOUR TITLE");
        toolbarTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();

            }
        });
```

Comment: I know that, i was trying to pass the activity  (in the constructor) to the pager adapter,because I need it there and was trying to do this with MyActivity.class and not MyActivity.this, lol

Comment: @Emuna613 means you want to set title from the pager adapter ??

Comment: yes I was. I've changed the implementation since then, Thanks anyway @Garg's